# Does anyone know how to get FitBit raw data?

Tags: fitbit

I need to crack fitbit signal for work at college and have no idea how to access the signal from bluetooth. Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently get fitbit data. The only way is thorough the web api and it's not real time. Check this [documentation](https://dev.fitbit.com/reference/).